# How to kill waiting threads in producer consumer problem

Tags: c, multithreading

[code snippet
source-Remzi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByYGw.jpg)

I'm writing producer consumer problem using lock and condition variable. It is a simple program where I use int in buffer. How do I stop consumer from waiting after the producer has finished producing?

```
void do_fill(int i){
    buffer[fill_ptr].chunkNumber = i;
    buffer[fill_ptr].size = 1024;
    buffer[fill_ptr].startPointer = dst + (i * 1024);
    fill_ptr = (fill_ptr+1) % max;
    numfull++;
}

int do_get(){
    int temp_chunk = buffer[use_ptr].chunkNumber;
    char *temp_start = buffer[use_ptr].startPointer;
    int temp_size = buffer[use_ptr].size;
    use_ptr = (use_ptr+1) %max;
    printf("%d  %c  %d \n", temp_chunk,*temp_start,temp_size);
    numfull--;
    return temp_chunk;
}

void *producer(void *arg) 
{
    
    for (int cant = 0; cant < 5; ++cant)
    {
        printf("IN PRODUCER\n");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);           // p1
        while (numfull == max)  // p2
            pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &m);  // p3
        do_fill(cant);               // p4
        pthread_cond_signal(&fill);       // p5
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);  
    } 
}

void *consumer(void *arg) 
{  
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("IN CONS\n");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
               // c1
        while (numfull == 0)
        {
          // c2
            pthread_cond_wait(&fill, &m);
        }  // c3
        int temp = do_get();
        pthread_cond_signal(&empty);      // c5
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);        // c6
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste your code as text instead of showing a screenshot. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question It is difficult to give advice without seeing the missing functions. Maybe there is a way to detect a "no more data"/EOF condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a second variable `bool is_finished = false`, which, like the variable `numfull`, is protected by the mutex `m`. When the producer is finished, it sets this variable to `true` and signals the condition variable `fill`.

This is what the function `producer` could look like:

```
void *producer(void *arg) 
{ 
    for (int cant = 0; cant < 5; ++cant)
    {
        printf("IN PRODUCER\n");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
        while (numfull == max)
            pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &m);
        do_fill(cant);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
        pthread_cond_signal(&fill);
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    is_finished = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    pthread_cond_signal(&fill); 
}
```

The function `consumer` must of course be changed accordingly, for example to the following:

```
void *consumer(void *arg) 
{  
    for (;;) //infinite loop
    {
        printf("IN CONS\n");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
        while ( numfull == 0 && !is_finished )
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&fill, &m);
        }
        if ( numfull == 0 )
        {
            //is_finished must be true
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
            break;
        }
        int temp = do_get();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
        // It is generally recommended to signal only after
        // releasing the mutex, otherwise the awakened thread
        // may block on the mutex.
        pthread_cond_signal(&empty);
    }
}
```

In the function `consumer`, I also changed the `for` loop to an infinite loop, because it didn't make sense to limit it to 5 iterations. It should instead wait for the producer to signal that it is finished.

Comment: The consumer thread will not wait but in that case the for loop will still continue and it will keep on printing garbage values

Comment: @AdityaKulkarni: You must of course check both predicates (`numfull` and `is_finished`) after exiting the while loop, in order to determine whether to continue consuming or to stop.

Comment: @AdityaKulkarni: I have now added the full `consumer` function.

Comment: In your question, I don't understand why the `for` loops in `consumer` and `producer` are both limited to 5 iterations. It would make more sense for the `consumer` loop to be infinite, so that it only exits the loop when producer signals that it is finished. Only the `producer` should be limited to 5 iterations.

Comment: Generally, the predicates of a condition variable should be protected by the mutex. However, you are modifying `is_finished` without first aquiring the mutex. I'm not sure if this is a good idea. However, in this case, it probably will not matter, because it is the only thread writing to that variable and all other reads only read from it. At least if all write and read operations are atomic, it should not be a problem. But I would still recommend locking the mutex, just to be safe.

Comment: @AdityaKulkarni: If the consumer completes the 5th iteration of the loop and inspects both predicates (`numfull` and `is_finished`) in the 6th iteration of the loop before the producer sets `is_finished` to true (which is possible), then the consumer will begin waiting on the condition variable. If the producer never signals the condition variable after setting `is_finished` to true, then the consumer will wait forever on the condition variable. This is a deadlock. That is why it must be signalled after setting `is_finished` to true.